# Respect X-Frame-Options with HTTP redirect

Tags: redirect, http-headers, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I'm testing clickjacking mitigation with a simple page like this on another domain:

```
<iframe src="https://my.domain/login"></iframe>
```

My login page sends the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://my.domain/landing
...
```

I'm surprised to see both IE 10 and Chrome 33 follow the redirect and display my landing page inside the `<iframe>`. My landing page does not send `X-Frame-Options`, but I expected the first `X-Frame-Options` on the login page to trump the redirect. How can I prevent browsers from following the redirect when my login page is displayed in a frame?

I should add that things work as expected (`<iframe>` is empty/blocked) if the login page doesn't send an HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the terminology used in [RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034), I conclude that browsers will not apply X-Frame-Options restrictions for HTTP redirects (status codes 301, 302, etc), but rather for any response where the browser processes the content, e.g.:

> The use of "X-Frame-Options" allows a web page from host B to
> declare that its content (for example, a button, links, text, etc.)
> must not be **displayed** in a frame (`<frame>` or `<iframe>`) of another
> page (e.g., from host A).  This is done by a policy declared in the
> HTTP header and enforced by browser implementations as documented
> here.

or:

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP header field indicates a policy that
> specifies whether the browser should **render** the transmitted resource
> within a `<frame>` or an `<iframe>`.  Servers can declare this policy in
> the header of their HTTP responses to prevent clickjacking attacks,
> which ensures that their content is not embedded into other pages or
> frames.

As an alternative for the login page you could return a HTTP status code 200 and a meta-tag or javascript for redirection, the X-Frame-Option will then apply, but I admit that it's ugly.